# How to add SEO keywords in SharePoint interne Site

Tags: sharepoint-server, seo

Hi I want to add some SEO keywords in my SharePoint interne Site ,how to add these keywords in master page
is can i create individual meta tags for each keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SEO Keywords can only be addded into Publishing Pages instead of Master Page in SharePoint:

[image]

[image]

Reference:

[Search Engine Optimization in SharePoint 2013](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/search-engine-optimization-in-sharepoint-2013/)